# Regular Expression - Regex expression between 0 and 13.6

Tags: regex

I've been asked on how to do a regex expression bewtween 0 and 13.6, but i really dont know.. anyone could help?

Thanks

Comment: I've looked some examples, but could make it less than a specific double

Comment: What language are we talking about?

Comment: [Please post the code you've attempted](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: Regular expressions are not usually the best tool for checking numeric ranges. Why do you need to do it this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
^([0-9](?:\.[0-9]+)?|1[0-2](?:\.[0-9]+)?|13(?:\.[0-5][0-9]+)?|13(?:\.60*)?)$
```

Comment: i've not tested.. but it's similar to what i got working. Thanks

Comment: Didn't see that you got solution for this, didn't know that you have a working one already.

Comment: This has issues. It won't match `13`, `13.0`, or `13.12`. You're allowing `0-12` to have optional decimals and multiple decimal places. But for `13`, it must be: `13.1`, `13.2`, `13.3`, `13.4`, `13.5`, or `13.6` only.

Comment: corrected the regexp. but  I dont understand clearly, how many digits can have after the decimal point?

Answer (score 0):

```
(?<![\.\d])\d\b(?:\.\d+)?|(?<=1)[0-2]\b(?:\.\d+)?|(?<=13)\.?[0-2]?|(?<=13.5)(?:\.\d+)?|13\.6
```

this will find every instance that exists in a string, doesnt necessarily have to start and end as the number